# Apache Nifi - How to specify partition to read data from in Kafka Consumer

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-nifi

**Use case:**
We have golden gate kafka big data adapter configured for multiple schema. 
Each schema is mapped to 1 partition and kafka partitioner publish messages as per defined mapping. like 
schema1=1(Partition#1),schema2=2 .. scheman=n

This way messages of all schemas isolated in their own partitions.

**Problem:**
Given the scenario, i want to configure 1 instance of Apachi Nifi node to process 1 partition of kafka topic. This way, i will configure 100 Nifi instances running in parallel processing 100 kafka partition.

But i don't see any place where i can specify partition in KafkaConsumer

[image]
[image]

**Question:**

1. Does Apache Nifi kafka consumer support partition configuration?
2. If it doesn't support, Is it in road map for future release?

Kafka Version: 0.10.1.1 
Apache Nifi Version: 1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't specify the partition to consume from, it is automatically determined by the Apache Kafka client which ensures that only one consumer in a consumer group is assigned to a given partition. Basically, a single consumer can consume from multiple partitions, but different consumers can't consume from the same partition.

So if you had 100 ConsumeKafka processors in the same NiFi instance where they all had the same consumer group, then each processor would be assigned 1 of the 100 partitions.

I could see the value of possibly exposing a property to select a partition in the future.

Also, you probably want to use ConsumeKafka_0_10 with Kafka 0.10.1.1, ConsumeKafka uses the 0.9 client and it is usually best to use the client that lines up with the broker.